# How to remove redundant ID field in auto-generated ManyToMany table in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have two classes in my `models.py` file:

```
class Person:
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Course:
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    course_person = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

In my modified example, one person is takes many courses and one course is taken by many people, hence ManyToMany.

When I let Django auto-generate my table, I get an extra `ID` field.
I want the autogenerated `person_course` manytomany table to consist of the two composite keys `person_id` and `course_id` only. *Note*: Both of them are auto-generated, auto-incremented fields.

I have also tried defining my ManyToMany class and attempted to link the fields using the keyword `through=`, but that did not help.

I have asked Google but without much help. Many some geniuses among you can provide some hint :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django currently [does not support composite primary key by default](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys#Multi-ColumnPrimaryKeysupport)

What you can do instead is keep the auto generated `id` as the (surrogate) primary key and then define a [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) relationship in the `through` table.

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (course, person)
```

This way, you can guarantee unique entries in the through table, and when you reference the `id` it is the equivalent of referencing the unique `(course, person)` which is what we want anyways.

There are some [third party apps](https://django-composite-field.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#compositefield) that implement this feature if you want. However, unless an absolute necessity (like a legacy system support), I would just keep it simple and implement `unique_together`.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Well, it is a limitation from Django not to be able to do that. Django tries to make life easy. I used to design databases from scratch for use in my apps and I am not so happy that Django tries to do everything itself. At least, I do not have that much control on _some_ things, like not creating the redundant ID field. I use MySQL workbench to visually depict my databases, and this extra ID field doesn't look good. Anyway, since it doesn't affect the app logic, I can live with that :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
```